# Unable to compile TensorFlow from source on an Intel i7 930 CPU; GTS-250 GPU

Tags: tensorflow, compiler-errors, bazel, avx

I'm new to TF and want to do a compile from source as my desktop does not have a CPU or GPU that supports AVX instructions.  My system has an Intel i7 930 processor (Bloomfield from the nehalem family) and a Nvidea GTS-250 CPU.  Yeah I know, both are getting long in the teeth.

The following is the full stack where I am failing in the process.  I am following instructions from the following webpage.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

I pushed forward with the compile and ended up seeing the following errors...

```
H:\Python\TensorFlowCompile\tensorflow>python ./configure.py
WARNING: --batch mode is deprecated. Please instead explicitly shut down your Bazel server using the command "bazel shutdown".
You have bazel 0.29.1 installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is C:\Users\Zeek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe]:


Found possible Python library paths:
  C:\Users\Zeek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [C:\Users\Zeek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages]

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with XLA JIT support? [y/N]: N
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with ROCm support? [y/N]: N
No ROCm support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: N
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is /arch:AVX]: --config=v2 -march=nehalem


Would you like to override eigen strong inline for some C++ compilation to reduce the compilation time? [Y/n]: Y
Eigen strong inline overridden.

Preconfigured Bazel build configs. You can use any of the below by adding "--config=<>" to your build command. See .bazelrc for more details.
        --config=mkl            # Build with MKL support.
        --config=monolithic     # Config for mostly static monolithic build.
        --config=ngraph         # Build with Intel nGraph support.
        --config=numa           # Build with NUMA support.
        --config=dynamic_kernels        # (Experimental) Build kernels into separate shared objects.
        --config=v2             # Build TensorFlow 2.x instead of 1.x.
Preconfigured Bazel build configs to DISABLE default on features:
        --config=noaws          # Disable AWS S3 filesystem support.
        --config=nogcp          # Disable GCP support.
        --config=nohdfs         # Disable HDFS support.
        --config=nonccl         # Disable NVIDIA NCCL support.

H:\Python\TensorFlowCompile\tensorflow>bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=0 --terminal_columns=269
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  'build' options: --python_path=C:/Users/Zeek/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from h:\python\tensorflowcompile\tensorflow\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --apple_platform_type=macos --define framework_shared_object=true --define open_source_build=true --java_toolchain=//third_party/toolchains/java:tf_java_toolchain --host_java_toolchain=//third_party/toolchains/java:tf_java_toolchain --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --spawn_strategy=standalone --strategy=Genrule=standalone -c opt --cxxopt=-std=c++14 --host_cxxopt=-std=c++14 --announce_rc --define=grpc_no_ares=true --define=PREFIX=/usr --define=LIBDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib --define=INCLUDEDIR=$(PREFIX)/include --config=v2
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from h:\python\tensorflowcompile\tensorflow\.tf_configure.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/Zeek/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/Zeek/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/lib/site-packages --python_path=C:/Users/Zeek/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe --config monolithic --copt=-w --host_copt=-w --copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --host_copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --copt=-DNOGDI --host_copt=-DNOGDI --verbose_failures --distinct_host_configuration=false --define=override_eigen_strong_inline=true --action_env TF_CONFIGURE_IOS=0
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:v2 in file h:\python\tensorflowcompile\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define=tf_api_version=2
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:monolithic in file h:\python\tensorflowcompile\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define framework_shared_object=false
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:monolithic in file h:\python\tensorflowcompile\tensorflow\.bazelrc: --define framework_shared_object=false
Loading:
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (6 packages loaded, 18 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (6 packages loaded, 18 targets configured)
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (6 packages loaded, 18 targets configured)
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'com_google_protobuf' which is a tf_http_archive (rule definition at H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:121:19):
 - H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace.bzl:434:5
 - H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:19:1
Analyzing: target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (6 packages loaded, 18 targets configured)
INFO: Repository 'com_google_protobuf' used the following cache hits instead of downloading the corresponding file.
 * Hash 'b9e92f9af8819bbbc514e2902aec860415b70209f31dfc8c4fa72515a5df9d59' for https://storage.googleapis.com/mirror.tensorflow.org/github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/310ba5ee72661c081129eb878c1bbcec936b20f0.tar.gz
If the definition of 'com_google_protobuf' was updated, verify that the hashes were also updated.
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'com_google_protobuf':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl", line 101
                _apply_patch(ctx, ctx.attr.patch_file)
        File "H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl", line 68, in _apply_patch
                _execute_and_check_ret_code(ctx, cmd)
        File "H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl", line 52, in _execute_and_check_ret_code
                fail("Non-zero return code({1}) when ...))
Non-zero return code(127) when executing 'C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -l -c "patch" "-p1" "-d" "C:/users/Zeek/_bazel_Zeek/hfhzrtpt/external/com_google_protobuf" "-i" "H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/third_party/protobuf/protobuf.patch"':
Stdout:
Stderr: /usr/bin/bash: patch: command not found
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: no such package '@com_google_protobuf//': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl", line 101
                _apply_patch(ctx, ctx.attr.patch_file)
        File "H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl", line 68, in _apply_patch
                _execute_and_check_ret_code(ctx, cmd)
        File "H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl", line 52, in _execute_and_check_ret_code
                fail("Non-zero return code({1}) when ...))
Non-zero return code(127) when executing 'C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -l -c "patch" "-p1" "-d" "C:/users/Zeek/_bazel_Zeek/hfhzrtpt/external/com_google_protobuf" "-i" "H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/third_party/protobuf/protobuf.patch"':
Stdout:
Stderr: /usr/bin/bash: patch: command not found
INFO: Elapsed time: 19.298s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (6 packages loaded, 18 targets configured)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (6 packages loaded, 18 targets configured)
```

**I ran with a newer version of bazel prior to this compile and I was presented with the following error so that is why I reverted back to 0.29.1**

```
H:\Python\TensorFlowCompile\tensorflow>python ./configure.py
Extracting Bazel installation...
WARNING: --batch mode is deprecated. Please instead explicitly shut down your Bazel server using the command "bazel shutdown".
You have bazel 1.0.1 installed.
Please downgrade your bazel installation to version 0.29.1 or lower to build TensorFlow! To downgrade: download the installer for the old version (from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases) then run the installer.
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong, I am still pretty new at this so it's probably something pretty glaring/easy....
[Edit] this seemed to be resolved by setting up patch s it wasn't installed:
pacman -Syuu patch

**I pushed a bit farther and now I'm failing at the zip stage as follows.. **

```
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...

[0 / 23] [Prepa] PythonZipper tensorflow/python/keras/api/create_tensorflow.python_api_1_keras_python_api_gen_compat_v1.zip ... (3 actions, 0 running)
ERROR: H:/python/tensorflowcompile/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/python/BUILD:46:1: PythonZipper tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.zip failed (Exit 255)
FATAL: MappedOutputFile(bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.zip): CreateFileMapping failed
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 38.195s, Critical Path: 4.35s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

**I then tried to go back to the python config stage to make sure that I picked v2 and the proper family of CPU but when I redo the compile I see ANOTHER error where it is failing much sooner.. **

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unrecoverable error while evaluating node 'REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY:@local_config_cc' (requested by nodes 'REPOSITORY:@local_config_cc')
at com.google.devtools.build.skyframe.AbstractParallelEvaluator$Evaluate.run(AbstractParallelEvaluator.java:528)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.concurrent.AbstractQueueVisitor$WrappedRunnable.run(AbstractQueueVisitor.java:399)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <> at index 60: C:/users/bill/_bazel_bill/hfhzrtpt/external/local_config_cc/*********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Auxiliary/Build/VCVARSALL.BAT
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.vfs.JavaIoFileSystem.getNioPath(JavaIoFileSystem.java:84)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.vfs.JavaIoFileSystem.exists(JavaIoFileSystem.java:119)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.vfs.Path.exists(Path.java:356)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.bazel.repository.skylark.SkylarkPath.exists(SkylarkPath.java:79)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.MethodDescriptor.call(MethodDescriptor.java:135)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.DotExpression.eval(DotExpression.java:126)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.DotExpression.doEval(DotExpression.java:51)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Expression.eval(Expression.java:75)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.UnaryOperatorExpression.doEval(UnaryOperatorExpression.java:98)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Expression.eval(Expression.java:75)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execIf(Eval.java:139)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execDispatch(Eval.java:214)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.exec(Eval.java:183)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.UserDefinedFunction.call(UserDefinedFunction.java:91)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.callWithArgArray(BaseFunction.java:474)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.call(BaseFunction.java:436)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.FuncallExpression.callFunction(FuncallExpression.java:992)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.FuncallExpression.doEval(FuncallExpression.java:904)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Expression.eval(Expression.java:75)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.UnaryOperatorExpression.doEval(UnaryOperatorExpression.java:98)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Expression.eval(Expression.java:75)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execIf(Eval.java:139)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execDispatch(Eval.java:214)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.exec(Eval.java:183)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.UserDefinedFunction.call(UserDefinedFunction.java:91)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.callWithArgArray(BaseFunction.java:474)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.call(BaseFunction.java:436)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.FuncallExpression.callFunction(FuncallExpression.java:992)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.FuncallExpression.doEval(FuncallExpression.java:904)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Expression.eval(Expression.java:75)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execAssignment(Eval.java:72)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execDispatch(Eval.java:192)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.exec(Eval.java:183)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execStatements(Eval.java:231)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execIf(Eval.java:144)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execDispatch(Eval.java:214)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.exec(Eval.java:183)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.UserDefinedFunction.call(UserDefinedFunction.java:91)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.callWithArgArray(BaseFunction.java:474)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.call(BaseFunction.java:436)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.FuncallExpression.callFunction(FuncallExpression.java:992)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.FuncallExpression.doEval(FuncallExpression.java:904)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Expression.eval(Expression.java:75)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execAssignment(Eval.java:72)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execDispatch(Eval.java:192)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.exec(Eval.java:183)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.UserDefinedFunction.call(UserDefinedFunction.java:91)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.callWithArgArray(BaseFunction.java:474)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.call(BaseFunction.java:436)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.FuncallExpression.callFunction(FuncallExpression.java:992)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.FuncallExpression.doEval(FuncallExpression.java:904)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Expression.eval(Expression.java:75)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execDispatch(Eval.java:201)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.exec(Eval.java:183)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execStatements(Eval.java:231)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execIfBranch(Eval.java:83)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execDispatch(Eval.java:198)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.exec(Eval.java:183)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execIf(Eval.java:140)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.execDispatch(Eval.java:214)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.Eval.exec(Eval.java:183)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.UserDefinedFunction.call(UserDefinedFunction.java:91)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.callWithArgArray(BaseFunction.java:474)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.BaseFunction.call(BaseFunction.java:436)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.bazel.repository.skylark.SkylarkRepositoryFunction.fetch(SkylarkRepositoryFunction.java:173)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.rules.repository.RepositoryDelegatorFunction.fetchRepository(RepositoryDelegatorFunction.java:298)
at com.google.devtools.build.lib.rules.repository.RepositoryDelegatorFunction.compute(RepositoryDelegatorFunction.java:225)
at com.google.devtools.build.skyframe.AbstractParallelEvaluator$Evaluate.run(AbstractParallelEvaluator.java:451)
... 7 more
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (231 packages loaded, 3779 targets configured)
WARNING: Waiting for server process to terminate (waited 5 seconds, waiting at most 60)

H:\Python\TensorFlowCompile\tensorflow>
```

Sorry folks I'm not sure where or how I show approach this one at this time... Is there a way to start the compile fresh, was there something that I missed that failed the pythonzip stage, was there a problem in my bezal config to start with....

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow doesn't yet support Bazel 1.x (it's coming, but not yet done), so yes you'll need 0.29.1 until then.

1. Set the environment variable to point to your VC directory, see ["Installing and Using Bazel" > "Installing on Windows" > "Troubleshooting" > "Problem: Bazel does not find Visual Studio or Visual C++"](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-windows.html#problem-bazel-does-not-find-visual-studio-or-visual-c).
2. Start a normal `cmd.exe` shell, no need to run the Visual Studio command line.
3. Install Python modules required by TensorFlow: `python -m pip install numpy keras_preprocessing`
4. Configure TensorFlow: `python configure.py`
5. Build the pip module: `bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

Comment: Would this be the best option for me in terms of an already compiled version?https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/2.0.0/py37/CPU/sse2

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What's with a compiled version?

Comment: @Belgrath: Your CPU supports SSE4.2 and popcnt, but not AVX.  You don't need to go all the way down to SSE2.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the responses all.  I was able to get TF working as listed above.  I've sense upgraded the CPU and GPUs too!